# ¿Cómo incluir un archivo XML dentro del ejecutable de mi proyecto?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

He creado un proyecto en *Visual Studio 2012 C#*. He agregado un archivo `.xml` y este archivo contiene información que la consola lee cuando es ejecutada.

Necesito publicarla para poder ejecutarla y poder dársela a las personas que me pidieron hacer esto.

Es que el archivo `.exe` puede ser encontrado en el directorio debug, pero esto no me sirve porque cuando la ejecuto en otra computadora dice que le faltan archivos relacionados a la consola (el archivo `xml`)

Cuando he publicado la consola, me da unos archivos en el directorio release, pero no incluye el `xml` y tampoco tengo que incluirlo para que sea visible ya que contiene información privada.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Sintáxis del archivo XML:

```
<root>
    <url></url>
</root>
```

En el código estoy usando `XmlDocument` con esto cargo mi archivo xml llamándolo por tag, o sea `GetElementsByTagName`, y así referencio el tag que quiero llamar adentro de un ciclo `for`.

Comment: ¿Dónde se encuentra el archivo XML que estaba haciendo para sus pruebas locales?, ese archivo es el que debe compartir con las personas que usted desee (es decir, obtiene el archivo .exe y el archivo XML "el que esté usando"). Por favor expanda un poco mas su pregunta sobre el origen y contenido del archivo XML.
Por cierto, recomiendo ampliar su pregunta con la información relacionada a la aplicación de consola; por ejemplo me gustaría saber: `¿cómo está leyendo la información del archivo XML, es posible que al ruta donde se encuentre el archivo es diferente entre los equipos?`

Comment: @Mauricio muchas gracias por la recomendacion. Tiene razon deberia haber hecho de otra forma la pregunta. El archivo xml esta en el repertorio bin. La consola lee dentro de ese archivo pero es privado y no tiene que ser espuesto a otras personas.

Comment: @A arancibia: por favor edite la pregunta con lo que me acaba de comentar. En este punto, no comprendo bien la relación .exe y XML si éste último no está expuesto a otras personas...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suponiendo que el IDE que manejas es Visual Studio, entonces usted puede embeber el archivo `xml` en el `.exe` como un recurso.

En las propiedades del proyecto que desea agregarlo, ir a la página de `Recursos` / `Agregar recurso` / añadir el `archivo existente.` *(esto difiere del lenguaje en el que este configurado el IDE)*

Una vez cargado el recurso usted podrá visualizarlo en la carpeta Properties.

Una de las maneras de cargar el archivo por código es esta:

```
XElement resource = XElement.Parse(Properties.Resources.MiArchivoCargado)
```

Donde `MiArchivoCargado` es el archivo que anteriormente usted cargo!.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Hice lo que me recomendaste y el problema que me dice que el resto d emi archivo sera trunqueado (el archivo contiene 30 lineas).

Comment: ¿tienes bien la sintaxis del xml?, puede ser por eso.

Comment: Mi documento empieza con <root> y tiene sub <tags>. he agreado en mi pregunta el formato de como esta mi documento.

Comment: si pruebas colocando un archivo nuevo. sin decirle que lo cargue de uno existente, y luego lo vas editando a tu acomodo?.

Comment: si resulto asi!! muchas gracias. Perdona con otro pregunta. Voy a colocar una parte de mi codigo que yo usaba antes usando xmlDocument, y para eso podia usar  xml.GetElementsByTagName. Ya que ahora lo cambie con XElement, ya no funciona usarlo de la misma forma. Que hay similar para eso?

Comment: Me encantaría poder ayudarte, pero entonces no vendría bien, dado que es otra pregunta distinta, porfa, califica la respuesta que te ayudó, y fórmula una pregunta nueva con el error que me mencionas, recuerda detallar bien la pregunta.

Comment: Si eso hare. Muchas gracias nuevamente!!

Answer (score 3):

Para que que aparezca el XML en el folder agrega el archivo XML al proyecto, una vez agregado le das click derecho, propiedades.

Allí encuentras la opción **Build Action** y la configuras con **Copy if newer**.

Sin embargo, dices que tampoco quieres hacerlo por un tema de datos privados, el tema es que si la aplicación debe acceder a esos datos entonces ya nunca serán privados y un usuario avanzado se podrá hacer a ellos sea como sea.

Como alternativas, y no te blindará al 100%, solo dejarían los datos un poco menos accesibles:

- No acceder al XML sino acceder al registro de Windows donde los valores esten configurados
- Publicar el XML en un sitio de la Intranet, la aplicación debería accederlos llamando la URI
- Funciona igual publicando el archivo en una ubicación Web

En todo caso podrías cifras los contenidos y que la aplicación los descifre, en cuyo caso tendrías que tener un certificado embebido en el `exe`.

La opción de **dejar el XML embebido** te debe poner a pensar al respecto de

> Si está embebido entonces mucho mejor no dejarlo embebido y dejarlo en el código, para efectos prácticos es lo mismo.

Otra alternativa más sofisticada es que la aplicación no lea ningún archivo sino que pida esos parámetros a un Web Service, si va o no cifrado depende de ti.

Como dato extra, los datos de configuración paramétricos de una aplicación raras veces están blindados del acceso por parte del usuario, yo en tu lugar mantendría el XML y la información privada la cifraria, siendo descifrable solo por la app a través de un certificado embebido que de igual forma seria accesible por un power user.

Answer (score 3):

Como te comentaron puedes embeber el archivo (dentro del mismo assembly) pero no lo podras modificar facilmente (sino es por codigo)
Podrias tener un archivo "por default" tambien que siempre vaya en la compilacion y tu app siempre lo intente leer desde la la ubicación del assembly que lo llama (.exe)

**TEMA 1: Guardar un variable de configuracion con el path del archivo**

Para los proyectos que tenemos archivos xml, y otro tipo de recursos utilizamos [AppSettings de ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)
Entonces, puedes ir hasta las propiedad de tu proyecto de consola y en Configuracion(Settings) agregar el item de configuracion por ejemplo "PathArchivo", algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para luego poder utilizarlo:

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Properties.Settings.Default.PathArchivo))
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Properties.Settings.Default.PathArchivo);
            //...
        }
```

Lo bueno de tener separado (y ubicarlo en un path) que es facil de cambiarlo/actualizarlo, podes utilizarlo en varias aplicaciones

**TEMA2: Para proteger...**

No te quedara otra que encriptar (asi como lo planteas), si lo quieres para eso es bueno utilizar [Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms995355.aspx) porque utiliza una clave unica por maquina, asi no tienes que compartir la clave. Pero ten en cuenta que como es unica por maquina, cuando llevas el mismo XML a otra maquina encriptado no funcionara. Pero tambien por esto la primera vez debes "encriptar" el archivo en la maquina donde se utiizara (aqui es comun tener un Aplicacion que solo realice esto, una unica vez, o la misma consola... que tenga comandos para encriptar un archivo)
Te dejo para que lo investigues [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) Proporciona los métodos para cifrar y descifrar los datos.

Lo bueno, que no necesitas compartir claves (pero lo malo es esto tambien ya que es unica por maquina/server) no puedes desencriptar en otra m aquina (PERO creo que se puede utilizar otro mecanimos con DPAPI para que lo haga
Ademas, tienes que ver "la primera vez", o sea cuando instalas el la app con el archivo (descomprimido) puedes hacer algo que hicimos una vez en un proyecto (tener un archivo.xml y si no esta encripta lo hace encripta la primera vez a archivo.dat o algo asi, y luego ya utiliza dicho archivo) todo esto lo haciamos con configuracion

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)
- [Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms995355.aspx)
- [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)